# Is this PC build OK and compatible

Tags: pc, compatibility

I'm a first time computer builder and I want to know is every thing in this build compatible. -thanks

- Intel - Core i3-7100 kabylake 3.9GHz Dual-Core Processor with stock cooler
- MSI - Z270-A PRO ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- Crucial - Ballistix Sport LT 8GB (1 x 8GB) DDR4-2400 Memory
- Western Digital - Caviar Blue 1TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive
- EVGA - GeForce GTX 1060 3GB 3GB GAMING Video Card
- Corsair - SPEC-ALPHA (Black/Red) ATX Mid Tower Case
- EVGA - 500W 80+ Certified ATX Power Supply

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is a build compatibility request. We can only provide recommendations for single components per question.

Comment: Try using [PC Part Picker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) if you want to verify your parts. It's quite difficult to check whether all parts are compatible just based on description.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is off-topic, but the build does seem compatible.

The i3-7100 is a LGA 1151 processor and is compatible with the Z270-A PRO (might be a bit overkill for an i3 that can't even overclock).

Hard drives work pretty much in any build, unless they use some special interface like an M.2 (the one you chose does not and is compatible).

You may want to refer to the motherboard supported list of RAM, but it should work fine in the motherboard.

The GPU is compatible with basically anything with a decent power supply (500W is enough) and a PCI-E x16 slot, which basically all motherboards have.

Anyways, I would actually recommend that you cut on the costs of the motherboard and increase the cost of the CPU, unless you plan to upgrade to another LGA 1151 CPU in the future. If you go with AMD, you can get the [Ryzen 5 1400](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113437) which is much more powerful than the i3-7100, and the motherboards for it cost less. The Ryzen 5 1400 paired with something like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813144029) will cost slightly more ($20-$40) than your current build, but will perform much better and better fits the GTX 1060.

Answer (score -1):

The Intel Pentium G4560 is a castrated i3 and hardly slower, maybe 10%. The Z-Board is a waste of money, especially if you do not overclock.
RAM seems legit on first glance but you lose dual channel which needs 2 RAM sticks to get slightly more performance.
Don't buy cards for around 200€ or more with only 3GB Video RAM, bad choice, rather go AMD with 8GB (470/570, 480/580) or Nvidia 6GB 1060.
You have to  check if your stuff fits in the case.

Budget? The goal is to build a gaming PC, right? What games? Other tasks which the PC has to master? An SSD instead of an old HDD would greatly reduce all of your loading and startup times, makes the PC much more responsive but gives you (almost) nothing for gaming.
Maximum and desired resolution (which is mostly GPU work)? Do you have some old hardware left? Etc. etc. Google and other tech/PC sites are a major help if you search a bit more, the forums there might also have guides which might answer your questions.

Edit: compatible? Seems so (if it fits into the case which it probably does but I don't know). Ahh and the mentioned i3-like pentium costs like half of the i3 or maybe even less.